# csocket : segmentation fault while sending linked list

Tags: c, list, sockets, send

I want to send a linked list from client to server in socket programming in c.Please can anyone help me in this..the following is the structure for the node in the linked list.

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node * next;
};
```

basically i want to send the linked list from client to server and then wants server to sort the linked list and return it to the client

client code:

```
#define MAX 100
#define PORT 5000
#define SA struct sockaddr
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main()
{

    struct node *a=NULL;
    a=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node *));

    int sockfd,connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cli;
    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sockfd==-1)
    {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n");
    bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    servaddr.sin_port=htons(PORT);
    if(connect(sockfd,(SA *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr))!=0)
    {
        printf("connection with the server failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("connected to the server..\n");

    printf("\nEnter the data");
    scanf("%d",&a->data);
    write(sockfd,&a,sizeof(a));
    printf("\ndata sent to the server");

    close(sockfd);
}
```

server code :

```
#define MAX 100
#define PORT 5000
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct node *a=NULL;
    a=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node *));

    int sockfd,connfd,len;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cli;
    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sockfd==-1)
    {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n");
    bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port=htons(PORT);
    if((bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)))!=0)
    {
        printf("socket bind failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully binded..\n");
    if((listen(sockfd,5))!=0)
    {
        printf("Listen failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Server listening..\n");
    len=sizeof(cli);
    connfd=accept(sockfd,NULL,NULL);
    if(connfd<0)
    {
        printf("server acccept failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("server acccept the client...\n");
    read(sockfd,&a,sizeof(a));
    printf("\ndata read from the client\n");
    printf("%d\n",a->data);
    close(sockfd);
}
```

i have just added 1 element to the linked list right now.
i am able to solve segmentation fault but the value which i am sending from client to server is being received wrong at the server.

Comment: It would be helpfull, if you provide all the code. If you can step through the programm with a debugger, to find out where the crash happens, add this information to your question. Thanks

Comment: 1) `a=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node *));` You allocate space for a pointer; you want space for a node. 2) `write(sockfd,&a,sizeof(a));` you send a pointer; you want to send a node 3) you cannot send pointers; they refer to objects on the local machine.

Comment: hello sir..can u help me how to do this..how to pass the linked list now..i m trying to make the corrections..but still not able to send

Answer (score 3):

First, pointer values from client's address space, even if on the same machine, don't make any sense on the server side, so I would suggest sending node values only.

Then, you need to check return values of `write()` and `read()` - they tell you how many bytes you were able to send and receive. The underlying issue here is that connected TCP socket gives you a full-duplex *stream* of bytes that does not know anything about your application-level "messages". This means one `write()` can correspond to multiple `read()`s and the other way around.

Also, following from the above, the receiving side needs to know how many bytes (or messages, if they are of known size) to expect. The easiest way to accomplish that in this particular example is to prepend your "list" message with number of items in the list.